# How to change Html tags using jQuery (or anything else)?

Tags: jquery, html, tags, web

How to change:

```
<p class="myClass">Lorem Ipsum (and maybe other nested tags)</p>
```

into:

```
<code class="myClass">Lorem Ipsum (and maybe other nested tags)</code>
```

?

This is an offline job. It's just an update but there are thousands of `p`s that I need to change into `code`s.

Comment: Are you saying you want to permanently update your source html? Most IDEs will let you do a find and replace across all the files in a project, as will tools like Notepadd++.

Comment: Why do you need or plan to make these changes on line or even off line at the client side ..?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, it's a permanent update. Find-replace will find `<p class="myClass">` and replace it with `<code class="myClass">`; but what about the ending `</p>` (obviously there are ending paragraphs that do't correspond to `<p class="myClass">`.

Comment: @hornetbzz It's a bug in iBooks that I need to overcome (the Html files will be the source for the ePubs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to obtain the element's children (including text nodes), then combine [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) and [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
$("p.myClass").contents().unwrap().wrapAll("<code class='myClass'></code>");
```

*Update:* If you have more than one `<p>` element, you have to iterate over them with [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to avoid reparenting all of them inside a single `<code>` element:

```
$("p.myClass").each(function() {
    $(this).contents().unwrap().wrapAll("<code class='myClass'></code>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not familiar with Jquery; I've just tried `$(document).ready(function() {
 $("p.code").contents().unwrap().wrapAll("<code class='code'></code>"); });` but what it does is that it puts the text from all `<p class="myClass">`s into one single `<code class="myClass">`. In other words, it replaces the first occurrence of `<p class="myClass"> ... </p>` with `<code class="myClass"> (the contents of all <p>s that have a class="myClass") </class>`.

Comment: Yup, that will indeed happen if you have several `<p>` elements. The solution is to iterate over them, see my updated answer.